# Get last 10 user's searches

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am writing chrome extension which requires to get last 10 user's searches from history. It seems this is saved in sqlite3 file 'History' in the user's profile directory. However the format of the table keyword_search_terms is not obvious. And I do not know how to get chrome's profile directory from extension's code. On Linux the directory is at '~/.config/chromium/Default' but I have no idea about what it will be in different environments.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to read a local file,

you can use [chrome.history api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html)

a basic example,

```
chrome.history.search({maxResults : 10, text: ""}, function(historyItem) {
   console.log(historyItem);
});
```

Don't forget to declare "history" permission in `manifest.json`.

**EDIT:** Yes this is for only last 10 URLS. API doesn't provide that functionality.

If you want to know where History file is located,

```
Windows Vista or 7: \Users\_username_\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
Windows XP: \Documents and Settings\_username_\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
Mac OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History
Linux: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/History
```

But I don't know how you will read data from an external file.

Comment: But this will return 10 last visited URLs. I am interested only in searches.